# website breaks when running this function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function:

```
function Test() {
                var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
                var res = "";
                var c = 1;
                var stoc = "";
                while (x > 0) {
                    var help = c.toString();
                    var h = help.length;
                    while (h > 0) {
                        res += help[h - 1];
                        h--;
                    }
                    if (res === help) {
                        stoc += res + ";" + " ";
                        x--;
                    }
                    c++;
                }
                document.getElementById("stoc").innerHTML = stoc;
            }
```

Whenever i trigger the function the button stays pushed and the site stops responding. The algorithm is supposed to return the first x polindrom (that are written the same way from right to left ex 121) numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Your browser is crashing because x is never getting decremented causing the loop to never exit. Check the value of help in the debugger.

Comment: I put everything out of the while loop and everything seemed ok (i wrote on my document help and x.

Comment: I figured it out. I was supposed to set res back to "". Because everytime the loop repeted it had the previous value.